# how to give popup for a panel?

Tags: development, jquery

I have panel control in my web part. I used some 10 controls in this panel with in a div so I need to show this div in the popup .so which I need to keep in popup either with panel ID or div ID.

```
{<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server"  >
<div>
ITEM FIELDS
</div>
<div ID="items">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:textbox ID="txtbox1" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:textbox ID="txtbox2" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:textbox ID="txtbox3" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:textbox ID="txtbox4" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:textbox ID="txtbox5" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:textbox ID="txtbox6" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
</td>
</tr>

<asp:link button ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" onclick="lnkbtn_onclick"></asp:link button>


</table>
<div>
</asp:panel>}
```

I need to show all these textbox controls in popup when I click on link button

Answer (score 2):

You have to use JQuery Plugin.
Wrap your panel elements inside a single div and create a close button for popup for example

```
    <div id='popup-wrapper'>
         <asp:panel.... All Text Boxes />
         <a id="close-btn" href="#">Close</a>
   </div>
```

Add following references to your page

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="modalPopLite1.3.1/modalPopLite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="modalPopLite1.3.1/modalPopLite.min.js"></script>
```

Call a simple script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () {    
  $('#popup-wrapper').modalPopLite({
  openButton: '#clicker', closeButton: '#close-btn' }); });
  </script>
```

[Details](http://www.mywebdeveloperblog.com/my-jquery-plugins/modalpoplite)

Comment: please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the SharePoint javascript model so that the popup look and feel will be the same as the OOTB popups, you will need to use the [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058%28v=office.14%29.aspx)  from the SP.UI namespace.

As you can see from the linked page, you can use the *"html"* option parameter to specify a dom element to display in the popup (**ignore where the documentation says that you must pass an html string - you must actually use a dom element**). So, at the bare minimum, you will have something like the following.

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
  html: document.getElementById(............),
  title: "Foo",
  ...
});
```

Be aware of one thing though: the showModalDialog process is "destructive". When the dialog closes, you will lose the dom element you used as an option parameter. This means two thing:

- You should resort to the dialog close handlers to pass the popup parameters / selected values to the original page
- if you need to open the popup multiple time, you should consider to clone the dom element before opening the popup.

Anyway, if you decide to follow this road, also consider as an option developing a separate page for the popup (and using the "url" dialog parameter). This way supporting multiple popup opening won't require additional work (you will still need to write code to handle passing parameters between the pages).